# SharePoint workflow - Daily Summary of All Changes

Tags: sharepoint-server, designer-workflow, sharepoint-designer-workflow, sharepoint-alerts

I am looking to create a daily summary of all changes (new items, modified items, deleted items) with a SharePoint workflow.
SharePoint's out of the box Alerts ALMOST provided all of the functionality I need to complete this but unfortunately, I can't send alerts to "user who created item" and that is a non-negotiable request from the customer.

Is there a way to accomplish what an alert could do using a workflow instead? So far I have been unable to create anything that works.

Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: What version of SharePoint are you using?

Answer (score 0):

From your description, you are using the SharePoint server which could send alerts for all changes(new items, modified items, deleted items).

Then you want to send the alert to the user who created the item, please try as follows:

1)Create a 2013 workflow in this list, set the trigger as shown below:

[image]

2)Then add the "Send an email" action to send an email to the user who created the item.

[image]

Unselect the new items alert then still use the modified items, deleted items alerts in this list.

Comment: thanks Julie! Unfortunately I need a  daily summary sent out for all items that have changed in a 24 hr period. The customer does not want one email per change

Comment: I don't think we could create a daily summary report you metioned use designer workflow.